# Z3 and let statement in C/C++

Tags: c++, z3, smt

SMT-LIB support a let statement:

```
 (let ((x1 t1) · · · (xn tn)) t)
```

Which statements must be used if the C/C++ library of Z3 is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no corresponding statement in C/C++, because it is not needed.

Note that SMTLib's `let` statement allows you to give a name to a subexpression so you can use it multiple times. If you want to do the same thing in C/C++, you'd simply use a C/C++ variable (of the right type) that contains that expression, and use it later on in building bigger expressions. So, in this sense, the `let` expression of SMTLib corresponds to the regular variables and expressions in C/C++.

*PS.* I suspect, however, you might actually have a different question about writing z3 programs in C/C++, and perhaps the way you formulated it is an instance of the so called [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you ask about exactly what you're trying to achieve, you'll no doubt receive a better answer.